Hypothesis testing: Alternative Hypothesis for Engle's ARCH test
This is a question about Engle’s ARCH test (Lagrange Multiplier test), specifically about its alternative hypothesis.
I suppose that the test is intended to detect the presence of conditional heteroskedasticity; not just to detect the violation of white noise. As a reminder, the test requires us to specify the maximum autoregressive order, m. In this sense, I presume that the alternative hypothesis needs to explicitly describe the presence of variance regimes. But my question is how?
First, let me set the null hypothesis as follows.
H0: The residual term of the squared time series has zero mean and a constant variance:
Thus, white noise and no ARCH effect.
Next, let me contemplate the following two potential alternative hypotheses: HA1 and HA2.

HA1: The residual term of the squared time series has non-zero mean
and a non-constant variance.
HA2: There is a significant serial correlation (autocorrelation) in the residual term of the squared time series for the past m observations: thus, there presents an ARCH effect (conditional variances).

While the first version is appealing for its simplicity, it does not help us to make any statistical inference about the conditional heteroskedasticity.
On the other hand, the second version states clearly about the conditional heteroskedasticity. Nevertheless, I am not sure if Engle’s ARCH test can assess this far.
Just to avoid any confusion, I am not claiming that either of them is the correct one. I just contemplated those for the sake of discussion.
What would be the correct set of null and alternative hypotheses for Engle’s ARCH test?
Thanks
